# How do I list the addesses in my keypool?

Tags: keypool

I want to list all of the addresses in my wallet, even the ones that aren't being used right now. I know that I can change the number of addresses with -keypool, but I want to list all of the addresses.

Answer (score 3):

Providing that you're referring to **BitcoinCore**, and that by "not being used right now" you mean there's no transaction associated with them yet, you can use this command to list them:

```
bitcoin-cli listreceivedbyaddress 0 true
```

The parameters are:

- minconf = 0
- includeempty = true

Comment: This command will return the already assigned (by `getnewaddress`) addresses, not the ones in the key pool.

Comment: Oh, you're right, thanks for pointing it out. Apart from that though, I have no other suggestion but try to manually extract it from the wallet file.

Answer (score 3):

That's a tricky one.

If you haven't modified the 'keypool' parameter then your key pool will contain 100 "unassigned" addresses. These addresses are controlled by your wallet but remain in a latent state in your client until you explicitly request for a new address.

The thing is that every time you request for a new address, a new one will be added to your key pool, so there will always be `X` number of latent addresses (where `X`: your keypool size) that cannot be accessed (by design) in an obvious way through the client.

Provided that there are `2^160` possible bitcoin addresses (while there is a total of `2^63` grains of sand on earth) a collision is practically impossible, therefore it is of little to no value to try to gain control over your keypool addresses which really only serve as a buffer so that you won't have to back-up your wallet after every single transaction.